# Keep the height of empty line in a tabular

Tags: tables

I would like to draw a table frame with some texts aligned center horizontaly and vertically, I used `tblr` enviroment of `tabularray` package, it fits most of my need except the empty line height, I would like to make the empty line share the same height of texted lines, but I can't figure it out. This is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]},
  stretch = 0,
  rowsep = 6pt,
  hlines = {0.5pt},
  vlines = {0.5pt},
}
      Name & Position & Unit & Sign & Notes \\
         &      &      &      & A1 \\
         &      &      &      & \\
         &      &      &      & \\
         &      &      &      & \\
         &      &      &      & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the page 21 of the documentation?

Comment: You could simply use the `\phantom{A1}` command in empty lines.

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem. I got all rows equal height! However, I f you like to have bigger height of all rows, just add option `rows = {<desired height>}`

Comment: Try on https://texlive.net/run .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key `rows` must become your friend...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]},
  stretch = 0,
  rowsep  = 6pt,
  hlines  = {0.5pt},
  vlines  = {0.5pt},
  rows    = {ht = \baselineskip} % <-- In the doc...
}
  Name & Position & Unit & Sign & Notes \\
       &          &      &      & A1    \\
       &          &      &      &       \\
       &          &      &      &       \\
       &          &      &      &       \\
       &          &      &      &       \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]